# Why is $\infty-\infty$ undefined in measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory, definition

Some additions to the title: I stumbled over this problem going through
my measure theory lecture notes; the author explicitly mentions that
he leaves $\infty-\infty$ undefined. I would like to know what goes
wrong, if I would define $l:=\infty-\infty$ for $l\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

I tried to derive contradictions by playing with arithmetical rules
in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ but couldn't obtain a contradiction.

> Here's an example where I merely try to obtain a contradiction by
>   assuming that $r:=\infty-\infty\in\mathbb{R}$ (as opposed to
>   $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$).
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}  & \infty=\infty\\ \Rightarrow & \infty=\infty+2\\
> > \Rightarrow &
> > \infty+\left(-\infty\right)=\left(\infty+2\right)+\left(-\infty\right)
> > \end{eqnarray*} an here the attempt breaks down, since this extended
>   addition doesn't have to be associative, so one can't conclude
>   \begin{eqnarray*} \Rightarrow & r=r+2\\ \Rightarrow & 0=2.
>  \end{eqnarray*}

**EDIT** A lot of people gave me answers in which they motivated why $\infty-\infty$ doesn't make sense. This is not what I'm looking for! Motivations are nice, but only a concrete contradiction gives certainty that it absolutely makes no sense to assign a number, or $\pm \infty$ to the above expression.

Comment: You need to define $l\cdot x$, $l+x$, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to define $\infty-\infty$ in the first place? That is, how would this symbol arise?

Comment: @Brad Just for the heck of it ;)

Comment: Well, you can define $\infty - \infty$ as you like. If you drop enough nice properties of addition/subtraction, you can avoid contradictions. But you need to sacrifice a lot of nice properties, so most people consider it better to leave $\infty - \infty$ undefined, which allows keeping most nice properties at least to a large extent.

Comment: @DanielFischer This sounds interesting. Could you maybe elaborate on it in an answer ?

Comment: I'd rather not. There's not much to elaborate, really. If you extend addition/subtraction from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ in an arbitrary manner, you don't get contradictions from that. You just get something that's not (very) useful anymore [but if you leave out a few points, you get something still quite useful from a particular extension]. After all, the additional properties besides being a map $A\times A \to A$ are what makes addition really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about what situations in measure theory might be described by $\infty-\infty$. Let $A=\mathbb R,B=(0,\infty)$. Then $m(A)=m(B)=\infty$, and
$$\infty-\infty\; \text{"="}\;m(A\setminus A)=0$$
yet
$$\infty-\infty\; \text{"="}\;m(A\setminus B)=\infty$$
so this can't be given a consistent definition.

Comment: This also isn't really a contradiction; merely a motivation to leave $\infty-\infty$ undefined, since we want $m(X\setminus Y)$ to be equal to $m(X)-m(y)$, which does not work $\infty$: This equality is only true if $m$ is a pairwise additive measure and $Y\subseteq X$ and $m(Y)<\infty$. Just because $\infty$ doesn't fit in this theorem doesn't invalidate other hypothetical uses of $\infty-\infty$ (only a contradiction would do that).

Comment: @user26698 No, it's not a contradiction. I'm answering why the author would leave $\infty-\infty$ undefined.

Comment: Agreed; though I still wonder, as I did in my question, what goes wrong (in the sense of "what contradiction appears") if you assign a value in the extended real line to $\infty-\infty$. (I've added an edit to hopefully make it clearer what I what.)

Answer (score 1):

If $l:=\infty-\infty\in \mathbb R$, then $1+l=1+(\infty-\infty)=(1+\infty)-\infty=\infty-\infty=l$, contradiction.

If $\infty-\infty=\infty$, then $-\infty=-(\infty-\infty)=-\infty+\infty = \infty-\infty=\infty$ and imilarly if $\infty-\infty=-\infty$.

So each possible choice of defining $\infty-\infty$ as a value in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ produces contradictions to the (desired) proerties of addition such as associativity and commutativity, as well as to $\infty\ne-\infty$.

You may have better luck in a one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$ where $\infty=-\infty$ holds. But that structure is unsuitable as a tool for measure theory.

Comment: I think your first chain of equalities is problematic since you use associativity to break up ∞−∞, which is not permitted, as I pointed out in my question

Answer (score 1):

There is really no point in trying to define $\infty - \infty$ if this is going to make addition non-commutative or even non-associative. The problem is the same as defining $\frac 00$ ($\infty$ is for addition, what $0$ is for multiplication, namely an absorbing element). Also you get problems with limits (which is one of the main reasons to include $\infty$ in measure theory in the first place), because for any $x \in [-\infty ,\infty ]$ there are sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty }a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty }b_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n-b_n)=x$, which screws up arithmetic of limits.

Comment: True, but saying that there is no point in defining it is not the same as highlighting a (concrete) contradiction.